# Problems with xmlhttp

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code to grab details from a webserver

```
<%@ LANGUAGE=VBScript%>
<%
vCustomerUserName = "name"
vCustomerPassword = "password"
vEventID = 123456
vEmail = "myname@me.com"
vPassword = "1122334455"

Response.Buffer=False 

Dim MyConnection
Dim TheURL

''# Specifying the URL
dataURL = "http://www.regonline.com/authorization.asmx/authorizeMemberWithEmailAddress"

Set MyConnection = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
''# Connecting to the URL
MyConnection.Open "POST", dataURL, False
MyConnection.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 

''# Sending and getting data
strQueryString = "customerUserName=" & vCustomerUserName & "&customerPassword=" & vCustomerPassword & "&eventID=" & vEventID & "&emailAddress=" & vEmail & "&password=" & vPassword

''# MyConnection.Send
MyConnection.Send strQueryString

TheData = MyConnection.responseText

''# Set the appropriate content type
Response.ContentType = MyConnection.getResponseHeader("Content-type")


Response.Write (TheData)

Set MyConnection = Nothing
%>
```

If I run this page in a browser it returns what appears to be an xml document. What I need to do is extract the value of a particular node and then send that to the browser in the form

```
response.write firstName=bob&lastName=smith
```

Could anyone please help me this is driving me mad and has taken a LONG time so far to get nowhere. I don't seem to be able to access the reply from the server as an xml document and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [responseXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757066%28VS.85%29.aspx) property instead of `responseText`. It is an instance of an [IXMLDOMDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756987%28VS.85%29.aspx) object. You can then use [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115.aspx) to select out the data you need via the [`selectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method.

This will not work if the content type of the response is not set to `text/xml` or `application/xml`. If this is the case, you can still use MSXML to load the responseText into a DOMDocument and select the data you need.

Another thing to note is that it is generally not recommend to use the XMLHTTP obect from a server side application. It is meant to be used from the client side, because in depends on WinInet. You should use [ServerXMLHttp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762278%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead. It has the same functionality, but depends on [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273%28VS.85%29.aspx) as opposed to WinInet. See the [FAQ](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290761) for more information.